# Parallel programming using OpenMPI : Program not running

Tags: parallel-processing, openmpi

So I am pretty new to the paradigm of parallel programming. I am trying to send across an indexed matrix from my root process (rank = 0) to a slave process (rank = 1). So I am using the following commands to run it :

- mpicc q_9.c -o q_9
- mpirun -np 2 ./q_9

The program compiles successfully, but doesn't run whatsoever. I have a feeling the MPI_Send() and MPI_Recv() routines aren't correctly synchronized. Any kind of help will go a long way. Below is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int curr_rank;
    int num_process;
    int i;
    int j;



    int in_matrix[4][4];
    int out_matrix[4][4];
    int num_rows = 4;
    int num_cols = 4;
    int displacement_array[4];
    int block_length[4];

    MPI_Datatype new_index_t;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_process);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &curr_rank);


    if(num_process == 2){
        if(curr_rank == 0){ /*Root process populates the matrix*/
            /*Initialize matrix*/
            for(i = 0 ; i < num_rows ; i++){
                for(j = 0 ; j < num_cols ; j++){
                in_matrix[i][j] = i + j;
                }
            }
        }

        for(i = 0 ; i < num_rows ; i++){
            displacement_array[i] = (num_rows * i) + num_rows;
            block_length[i] = (num_rows - i);
        }

        MPI_Type_indexed(num_rows, block_length, displacement_array, MPI_INT, &new_index_t);
        MPI_Type_commit(&new_index_t);

        if(curr_rank == 0){
            MPI_Send(in_matrix, 1, new_index_t, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
        else{
            for(i = 0 ; i < num_rows ; i++){
                for(j = 0 ; j < num_cols ; j++){
                    out_matrix[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }

            MPI_Recv(out_matrix, 1, new_index_t, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

            /*Indexed output matrix*/
            for(i = 0 ; i < num_rows ; i++){
                for(j = 0 ; j < num_cols ; j++){
                    printf("%d ", out_matrix[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

        }
    }
   MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**Edits:**

I run it on a different system and I get a message :
mpirun has exited due to process rank 0 with PID 10449 on
node abhijeet-mohanty-2 exiting improperly. There are three reasons this could occur:

1. this process did not call "init" before exiting, but others in
   the job did. This can cause a job to hang indefinitely while it waits
   for all processes to call "init". By rule, if one process calls "init",
   then ALL processes must call "init" prior to termination.
2. this process called "init", but exited without calling "finalize".
   By rule, all processes that call "init" MUST call "finalize" prior to
   exiting or it will be considered an "abnormal termination"
3. this process called "MPI_Abort" or "orte_abort" and the mca parameter
   orte_create_session_dirs is set to false. In this case, the run-time cannot
   detect that the abort call was an abnormal termination. Hence, the only
   error message you will receive is this one.

This may have caused other processes in the application to be
terminated by signals sent by mpirun (as reported here).

Comment: Runs fine on my machine.

Comment: Do you think the way MPI was installed is creating problems?

Comment: I am running it on Ubuntu 14.04 , if that helps.

Comment: You are missing a call to `MPI_Finalize` at the end of the program, otherwise it looks fine to me.

Comment: @HristoIliev Added MPI_Finalize() but to no avail.